# How to print values horizontally from the list followed by comma after each integer value in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I want to print values horizontally from list followed by comma after each integer value

```
alist = [1, 2, 3 4,5]

print(alist)
```

result should be like this:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: print( ", ".join( str(e) for e in alist ))

Answer (score 1):

print( ", ".join( str(e) for e in alist ))